# Special form of matrix

Tags: matrices, block-matrices

Consider the matrix defined by block :
$$
A =
\begin{bmatrix}
D_1 & B_{1,2} & \cdots & B_{1,n-1} \\
B_{1,2}^T &  & \cdots & B_{2,n-1} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
B_{1,n-1}^T & B_{2,n-2}^T & \cdots & D_n
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where $B_{i,j} = \Pi_{k=i}^{j-1} B_{k,k+1}$ (the $B$s are iterated products) and $D_i$ is diagonal.

Do matrix of this form have a name and are studied ?

Or maybe the simpler case of a matrix with the form
$$
A =
\begin{bmatrix}
d_1 & b_{1,2} & \cdots & b_{1,n-1} \\
b_{1,2} &  & \cdots & b_{2,n-1} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
b_{1,n-1} & b_{2,n-2} & \cdots & d_n
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where $b_{i,j} = b_{i,i+1}\dots b_{j-1,j}$.